# how to open chatbot automally when the page loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have embedded one chatbot in my website from third-party sites it is working properly. but, I want a chatbot which opens automatically, when the web page is loaded.

I have used this below code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    ! function(t, e) {
        "use strict";
        var r = function(t) {
            try {
                var r = e.head || e.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
                    a = e.createElement("script");
                a.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"), a.setAttribute("src", t), r.appendChild(a)
            } catch (t) {}
        };
        t.CollectId = "234567ertyusd3456", r("https://s3.amazonaws.com/collectchat/launcher.js")
    }(window, document);
</script>
```

can anyone suggest me a solution

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using [Collect.chat](http://collect.chat) to embed chatbot on your website. Here are two options you can try.

If you want to open chatbot immediately without any delay, add the following line of code inside the script

```
var CollectAlwaysOpen = true;
```

Instead, if you want a small delay after the user enters your website, You can set the delay from 'Settings > User targeting' page in [Collect.chat](http://collect.chat)'s  dashboard

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. it is working fine